# Meaning of the different Java CMS garbage collection logs memory sizes

Tags: java, garbage-collection

log entry of the concurrent mark sweep garbage collector contains information like (trimmed and line breaks inserted for readability) on Java-8:

```
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):
...
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 29612480K, used 994856K ...
2021-10-25T02:40:58.947+0200: 27.293: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-10-25T02:40:58.947+0200: 27.293:
  [ParNew: 996800K->110720K(996800K), 1.6650446 secs]
          1991656K->1859618K(30609280K), 1.6651368 secs] ...
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 0):
...
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 29612480K, used 1748898K ...
}
```

Question: How does the `mark-sweep generation ..., used 1748898K` relate to the the resulting sizes after the collection given by `->110720K` for ParNew and by `->1859618K`. From the wording I would have expected that maybe the sum of the two `->`-values should be hte `used` value. What does the `used` value mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 110720K is what survived from the young generation.
- 1859618K is the    occupied space in the entire heap.
- 1748898K is the space used in the    old generation (1859618K - 110720K = 1748898K)